# Variadic function with restricted types

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, template-meta-programming, variadic

I am designing a class which (among other things) acts as a vertex in an undirected graph.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

class Node
{
public:
    explicit Node(const std::string& name);
    Node(const Node&);
    Node(Node&&);

    class iterator
        : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, const Node>
    {
        //...
    };
    class container_proxy
    {
    public:
        iterator begin() const;
        iterator end() const;
    private:
        //...
    };

    container_proxy neighbors() const;

    add_link(Node& other);

    //...

private:
    //...
};
// to support: for (const Node& neighbor : node.neighbors())
Node::iterator begin(const Node::container_proxy&);
Node::iterator end(const Node::container_proxy&);
```

Now I want to define a function `link_complete` which:

- takes any number of arguments
- allows non-`const` `Node` lvalues (parameter type `Node&`)
- allows non-`const` `Node` rvalues (parameter type `Node&&`)
- does not allow any other parameter type.

An example usage:

```
Node ret_by_value();

void example_test(Node& x, Node&& y)
{
    link_complete(x, ret_by_value(), std::move(y), Node("test"));
}
```

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <type_traits>

class Node {
    //...
public:
    static void link_complete(std::initializer_list<Node*> node_list);
};

template <typename ... Types>
struct template_all; // UNDEFINED

template <>
struct template_all<>
  : public std::true_type {};

template <typename ... Types>
struct template_all<std::false_type, Types...>
  : public std::false_type {};

template <typename ... Types>
struct template_all<std::true_type, Types...>
  : public template_all<Types...>::type {};

template <typename ... Args>
auto link_complete(Args&& ... args) ->
  typename std::enable_if<
    template_all<
      typename std::is_same<
        typename std::remove_reference<Args>::type,
        Node
      >::type ...
    >::value,
    void
  >::type
{
    Node::link_complete( { &args... } );
}
```

It seems to work as required, but I'm wondering if there was a simpler or "prettier" way to do it, or maybe a way to improve that `template_all` helper type.  All C++11, TR1, and Boost features are welcome.  I did notice [`boost::mpl::and_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/and.html) looks similar to my `template_all` helper type, but Boost MPL seems like a tricky learning curve and/or overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `struct` has `public` inheritance

By default, `struct` has `public` inheritance. Therefore, you don't need to manually specify it every time. You can write shorter (and so more readable) code:

```
template <>
struct template_all<>
  : std::true_type {};

template <typename ... Types>
struct template_all<std::false_type, Types...>
  : std::false_type {};

template <typename ... Types>
struct template_all<std::true_type, Types...>
  : template_all<Types...>::type {};
```

Since type traits generally use many templates, you don't want to add even more extra keywords all over the place.

## Use alias templates

If you have acces to a compiler that supports some C++14 features, you will probably want to use the alias templates for transformation traits to get rid of many `typename` and `::type`. Unfortunately, the alias templates for the query traits (`is_*`) have not been accepted, so you have to use `std::is_same`.

```
template <typename ... Args>
auto link_complete(Args&& ... args) ->
  std::enable_if_t<
    template_all<
      typename std::is_same<
        std::remove_reference_t<Args>,
        Node
      >...
    >::value,
    void
  >
{
    Node::link_complete( { &args... } );
}
```

## `static_assert` is great

Instead of using SFINAE for `link_complete`, you should use `static_assert` since your function does not have any overload. It will allow you to give a meaningful error message instead of a somewhat obscure SFINAE error message:

```
template <typename ... Args>
void link_complete(Args&& ... args)
{

    static_assert(
        template_all<
            typename std::is_same<
                std::remove_reference_t<Args>,
                Node
            >::type...
        >::value,
        "link_complete arguments must be of the type Node"
    );

    Node::link_complete( { &args... } );
}
```

## You may want to use [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)

`std::decay` calls `std::remove_reference` and `std::remove_cv` internally. If needed, it also calls `std::remove_extent` if `T` is an array type and calls `std::add_pointer` if `T` is a function type. In short:

> This is the type conversion applied to all function arguments when passed by value.

That allows you to check for what we generally think of as "same types":

```
template <typename ... Args>
void link_complete(Args&& ... args)
{

    static_assert(
        template_all<
            typename std::is_same<
                std::decay_t<Args>,
                Node
            >::type...
        >::value,
        "link_complete arguments must be of the type Node"
    );

    Node::link_complete( { &args... } );
}
```

## Rethink `template_all`

All in all, your goal is to test boolean conditions on types. Since the query traits have a `static constexpr bool value` member, you may want to create a `template_all` that checks for `true` and `false` (like `std::enable_if` or `std::conditional`) instead of checking for `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`. That would make your intent clearer, but it would be more like a `all_true` template.

```
template <bool...>
struct all_true; // UNDEFINED

template <>
struct all_true<>
  : std::true_type {};

template <bool... Conds>
struct all_true<false, Conds...>
  : std::false_type {};

template <bool... Conds>
struct all_true<true, Conds...>
  : all_true<Conds...> {};

template <typename ... Args>
void link_complete(Args&& ...)
{
    static_assert(
        all_true<
            std::is_same<
                std::decay_t<Args>,
                Node
            >::value...
        >::value,
        "must have Node types"
    );

    Node::link_complete( { &args... } );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed look.  I specifically don't want to `remove_cv` in this case.  Omitting base class access rubs my style-meter the wrong way, but that's mostly preference.  I like `all_true` (and can't really remember why I thought using type parameters was a good idea at the time).

Comment: @aschepler I tend to consider that `class` or `struct` is enough to document `public`/`private` access, but I have to admit that beginners simply don't know the difference, so explicitly specifying it isn't bad either ^^